# Promises are not resolving in order

Tags: javascript, promise, chain

From ProcessSearch I am returning a Promise.all with some more promises chained on. I then try to chain more to the returned promise but these resolve before the returned promise.

**Logs:**

```
Search called
Searching: hello
Searching: hello
Search:https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?mkt=en-us&offset=0&q=hello
DatabaseClient: getResults
DatabaseClient: getResults
Results:   ******THIS SHOUOLD BE AFTER BELOW***
Number of Results: 9
values: 2
newResults: 9 oldResults: 0 deduplicated: 9
DatabaseClient: saveKeywords: number of keywords:undefined
DatabaseClient: saveResults: number of results:9
DatabaseClient: saveResults resolve
```

---

```
router.post('/search', function(req, res, next){
console.log('Search called');
var body = req.body;
var searchString = body.searchString;
console.log('Searching: ' + searchString);
searchProcessor.ProcessSearch(searchString, databaseClient)
.then(
    databaseClient.getResults()
    .then( results =>
        console.log("Results: "  + results)
    )
).catch(error => console.log("ERROR: " + error));
})


exports.ProcessSearch = function processSearch(searchString, databaseClient)
{
  console.log("Searching: " + searchString);
  var searchPromise = searchClient.search(searchString)
    .then(results => {
      // Add keywords
      console.log("Number of Results: " + results.length)
      return results;
    });

  var getSavedResultsPromise = databaseClient.getResults();

  return Promise.all([searchPromise, getSavedResultsPromise])
  .then( values => {
    console.log("values: " + values.length)
    var searchResults = values[0];
    var savedResults = values[1];
    var newResults = deduplicate(searchResults, savedResults, (result) => {return result.url});
    var newKeywordsToOccurances = addKeywords(newResults);
    databaseClient.saveKeywords(newKeywordsToOccurances);
    return databaseClient.saveResults(newResults);
  })
}
```

Comment: You must pass a *function* as a callback to `then`, not a promise.

Comment: @Bergi Im not sure I understand, could you give an example?

Comment: On the `searchProcessor.ProcessSearch(…)` promise, you call `.then()` put pass `databaseClient.getResults().then(…)` not a callback function. The `getResults` is called immediately, it doesn't wait for `ProcessSearch`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on where I called the function. By adding results => before the console.log(results) I guess it waits until the returned promise is executed instead of just moving forward.

```
router.post('/search', function(req, res, next){
console.log('Search called');
var body = req.body;
var searchString = body.searchString;
console.log('Searching: ' + searchString);
searchProcessor.ProcessSearch(searchString, databaseClient)
.then(
    databaseClient.getResults()
    .then( results =>
        console.log("Results: "  + results)
    )
).catch(error => console.log("ERROR: " + error));
})
```

Comment: Still not right for the reason given by Bergi above.